# Какие есть варианты вытаскивания данных из Google Sheets в Excel-файл?

Tags: php, javascript, excel, google-spreadsheet

Какие есть варианты вытаскивания данных из Google Sheets в Excel-файл?

Например есть таблица в Google и файл Excel. Мне нужно вытащить в Excel определенные данные из Google-файла — как можно это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скачать гуглодок в виде xlsx, открыть в Excel'е и макросом сделать всё что нужно.
Собственно, скачать можно тем же макросом.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, а макрос как-то может работать с двумя документами?

Comment: @Fitstd, да, макросу доступны все открытые в данный момент документы. Смотреть на коллекцию [`Workbooks`](//msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/office/ff841074.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

если программно, то есть встроенный API в гугл документе, там дается ссылка для работы с этим документом, пишите скрипт  нем, и работаете чере curl например. я чтение не делал( не было необходимости ) а вот добавление делал.